# How to determine which variables are state or input variables in dynamic modeling?

Tags: control-engineering, chemical-engineering, dynamics, process-engineering

When given a P&ID and a process flow diagram, and asked to determine which of the relevant variables to a process input variables, and which are state variables (eg.: mass flow, temperature, pressure, gas density...). Do you have any tips on how would you approach the classification of those variables?

Comment: These store something that carries over into the next, namely energy.  Look for the kinetic and potential energy.

Comment: Aren't state variables just the ones necessary to uniquely specify the state of the fluid (pressure, temperature, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tip:

There is a dynamic system modeling tool used by engineers called a *power bond graph* which is used to turn a dynamic system (gears, levers, hydraulic cylinders, DC motors, resistors, inductors, masses, etc.) into a graphical representation from which can be easily derived a full set of partial differential equations in matrix form that capture all the dynamics. The state variables and process inputs pop out in a natural way when cast in this form.

The standard reference in this field is Karnopp & Rosenberg, *System Dynamics: A Unified Approach*.